# ifup[260]: Error: ipv4: FIB table does not exist

Tags: networking, netplan

cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"

I installed ifupdown and removed netplan.io
but the command systemctl start networking fails
systemctl status networking

```
x networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/service.d
             `-zzz-lxc-service.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-09 15:09:22 UTC; 43s ago
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)
   Main PID: 164 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 195ms

Sep 09 15:09:21 test2 ifup[260]: Error: ipv4: FIB table does not exist.
Sep 09 15:09:21 test2 ifup[260]: Dump terminated
Sep 09 15:09:21 test2 ifup[164]: ifup: failed to bring up eth1
Sep 09 15:09:21 test2 ifup[269]: Setting up eth2
Sep 09 15:09:21 test2 ifup[277]: Error: ipv4: FIB table does not exist.
Sep 09 15:09:21 test2 ifup[277]: Dump terminated
Sep 09 15:09:21 test2 ifup[164]: ifup: failed to bring up eth2
```

it seems that iproute2 is blowing up when opening a table not offered by the kernel 5.15.53-1.
dpkg -l | grep iproute
ii  iproute2                    5.15.0-1ubuntu2

the question is: how do I fix this? it seems that a newer version of iproute2 is needed.

to be able to replace netplan (which does not support virtual devices)

Comment: What do you mean, "does not support virtual devices"?

Answer (score 0):

ifupdown is effectively obsoleted in Ubuntu as of 22.04.  It is included in the archive to support users who are upgrading from older releases and have not transitioned away from `/etc/network/interfaces`.  New deployments of ifupdown are unsupported.

Comment: Well, that's a huge mistake, since Netplan does not support virtual devices, i.e., is not par with ifupdown.

Comment: You have not explained what you mean by "does not support virtual devices".  There are lots of types of virtual devices supported by netplan.